# Is it possible to get a auto-generated values when using statement.getGeneratedKeys() in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, insert, last-insert-id

I am connecting mysql via java. I am trying to insert a record and i am finding the status using `statement.getGeneratedKeys()` and then `if (generatedKeys.next())`. Now can i get a value of coulmn which was inserted (ie) i have column named pass and it is an auto_increament column and it is my primary key and now i want to get the value which was inserted in this column. Is it possible??

Comment: AFAIK, MySQL doesn't allow non-primary key columns to be auto-increment. Did you mistag your question?

Comment: @perception my bad i missed it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard MySQL Connector J driver does support getting generated keys, yes. Here is some sample code:

```
final Connection conn ; // setup connection
final String SQL ; // define SQL template string

final PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
    SQL,
    Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

int affected = stmt.executeUpdate();
if (affected > 0) {
    final ResultSet keySet = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
    while (keySet.next()) {
        // these are your autogenerated keys, do something with them
        System.out.println(keySet.getInt(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Still I am getting java.sql.SQLException: Column 'pass' not found error.

Comment: You are not going to get that while iterating generated keys. Are you sure your insert statement isnt mismatching with your table schema?